# Bootstrap 3 - Navbar color when expanded

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a navbar in bootstrap 3. The Navbar is in blue and when a menu is opened (upon mouse hover), I would like to show the sub menus with background color of green.

Here is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/8jj2g4ym/2/

```css
li.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: blue;
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color:white;
    FONT-SIZE: 12pt;
    TEXT-DECORATION: none;
    FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
    WHITE-SPACE: nowrap;
    DISPLAY: block;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #333;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    background-color: green;
  }

.navbar-nav > li > a{
  padding-left:2px;
  padding-right:2px;
  margin-left:2px;
  margin-right:2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default"> 
  <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-left:2px;">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     
    
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu0 <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" style="cursor:pointer">Menu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
       <li ><a></a></li>
      </ul> 
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
      
        
      </ul>
      
    </div>
    
  </div>
</nav>
```

While the navbar is displayed as expected in blue, opened items have a background color of white (which I would like to be green).

I have added a style for this but it doesn't seem to have an impact.

```
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    background-color: green;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution:

Change some css rules to fit your needs:

```
li.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    background: #bacd63 !important;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    background: green !important;
  }
```

Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/8jj2g4ym/3/

Here the code snippet:

```css
li.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    background: #bacd63 !important;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: blue;
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color:white;
    FONT-SIZE: 12pt;
    TEXT-DECORATION: none;
    FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
    WHITE-SPACE: nowrap;
    DISPLAY: block;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #333;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    background: green !important;
  }

.navbar-nav > li > a{
  padding-left:2px;
  padding-right:2px;
  margin-left:2px;
  margin-right:2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default"> 
  <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-left:2px;">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     
    
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu0 <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" style="cursor:pointer">Menu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
       <li ><a></a></li>
      </ul> 
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
      
        
      </ul>
      
    </div>
    
  </div>
</nav>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! just one followup question. How to ensure font color is white? I tried color: white in the same CSS but font is still black.

Comment: Just add this rule: .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a { color: #fff !important; }

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu{background-color:green!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

added

```
.navbar-toggle:hover {
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

```css
li.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: blue;
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color:white;
    FONT-SIZE: 12pt;
    TEXT-DECORATION: none;
    FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
    WHITE-SPACE: nowrap;
    DISPLAY: block;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #333;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    background-color: green;
  }

.navbar-nav > li > a{
  padding-left:2px;
  padding-right:2px;
  margin-left:2px;
  margin-right:2px;
}

.navbar-toggle:hover {
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default"> 
  <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-left:2px;">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     
    
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu0 <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" style="cursor:pointer">Menu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
       <li ><a></a></li>
      </ul> 
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
      
        
      </ul>
      
    </div>
    
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
   background-color: green;
}
```

You should drop the `.open` selector, like this:

```
.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
   background-color: green;
}
```

This is because under the `ul` element (with the `navbar-nav` class) there is no element with the class `open`, so that is why the green background isn't applied.

Working code in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8jj2g4ym/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code dude....

Here is demo [Codepen](https://codepen.io/abianjali00/pen/gxrExX)

```js
    $(function() {
        $(".navbar-toggle").hover(
            function(){ $('.collapse').addClass('in') }
            
        );
    });

$(function() {
        $(".dropdown").hover(
            function(){ $(this).addClass('open') },
            function(){ $(this).removeClass('open') },
          function(){ $('.collapse').removeClass('in') }
        );
    });
$(function() {
        $("html").click(
          function(){ $('.collapse').removeClass('in') }
        );
    });
```

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover > .collapse {
    display: block;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: blue;
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
}


.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color:white;
    FONT-SIZE: 12pt;
    TEXT-DECORATION: none;
    FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
    WHITE-SPACE: nowrap;
    DISPLAY: block;
}

.navbar-collapse{
  background:green;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a{
  padding-left:2px;
  padding-right:2px;
  margin-left:2px;
  margin-right:2px;
}

.navbar-nav{
  margin:0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default"> 
  <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-left:2px;">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     
    
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu0 <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" style="cursor:pointer">Menu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
       <li ><a></a></li>
      </ul> 
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
      
        
      </ul>
      
    </div>
    
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
```